# Bicycle headlights with different low beam reflector types

Tags: optics

What makes second reflector different than first one in terms of efficiency and correct beam distribution (brighter below cut-off line, dimmer closer to the ground)?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The position of the led.

The lower diagram allows light directly from the led to escape in an upward direction, while that is not possible with the top version.

So, the “better” version, imho, is the top version...